# Which layout should I use (css inline-block equivalent)

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to build a specific layout for an android application. Actually, I would like to obtain something with the same behavior as inline-block div in html/css... I don't really know if I should use a LinearLayout or a GridLayout or something else...
It's like a horizontal LinearLayout but when the line is full, I would like my objects to go on the next line... I'm going to add the items programmatically to the container...

Here's an example of what I would like to do:

[image: a layout example]

Do you have any idea?

Thanks by advance,
Valentin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a layout, it might be easier to use a GridView because they will only use memory for items on screen and can be added using an adapter.

Read more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Answer (score 0):

Android provides a [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) component (along with the helper view [Space](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html) which can be used to build a flexible layout with multiple rows and columns, as explained in [The Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html). It is available as of Ice Cream Sandwich (v14) or as part of the v7 support library, and hence available to all 2.1+ devices.